# nextjs getInitialProps behaving strangely when navigating via link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, environment-variables, next.js

I need `getInitialProps` to run **server side** very time a page is rendered, but it seems it only runs on first render of a page in my project. Every subsequent render (e.g., I followed a link or pushed a new route via `Router.push(`\link`)`), only runs client side and I don't have access to ENV variables defined on the server-side, e.g. my GraphQL API_URL.

This is my project structure.

```
./pages
   _app.tsx
   index.tsx
   other.tsx
```

In `_app.tsx` I have the following

```js
class CustomApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }: AppContext) {
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    return { pageProps };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>My cool app</title>
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomApp;
```

In `index.tsx`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';

class Index extends Component {
  navigateToApplication = () => {
    Router.push('/other');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{width:100px, height:20px, color:red}} onClick={this.navigateToApplication}>      
        Click me!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

In `other.tsx` I have the following:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import config from '../src/config';

//Ensure the WizardComponent loads CLIENT SIDE. This makes the 'fetch' utility available for the gqlClient
const WizardComponent = dynamic(() => import('../src/components/layout/WizardComponent'), { ssr: false });

class Application extends Component {
 static async getInitialProps() {
    return { config };
  }

  render() {

    return <ApplicationWizard apiUrl={config.API_URL} />;
  }
}

export default Application;
```

In `config.ts` the following:

```js
import getConfig from 'next/config';
const nextConfig = getConfig();

const clientConfig = (nextConfig && nextConfig.publicRuntimeConfigå) || {};
const settings = Object.keys(process.env).length > 1 ? process.env : clientConfig;

const config = new (class {
  constructor(private readonly settings: Record<string, string | undefined>) {
    console.log('getting details', settings);
    console.log('NODE_ENV', this.settings['NODE_ENV']);
    console.log('API_URL', this.settings['API_URL']);
  }


  readonly ENVIRONMENT = process.env.ENVIRONMENT || this.settings['NODE_ENV'] || 'development';
  readonly API_URL = process.env.API_URL || this.settings['API_URL'] || 'http://localhost:4000/graphql';
})(settings);

export default config;
```

In `next.config.js` I have the following:

```js
const pick = require('lodash/pick');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withGraphql = require('next-plugin-graphql');
const path = require('path');

const nextConfig = {        

  webpack: (config, options) => {    
    config.resolve.alias['src'] = path.join(__dirname, 'src/');      
    return config;
  }
  ,publicRuntimeConfig : pick(process.env, ['NODE_ENV', 'API_URL']) 
};

module.exports = withPlugins([withCSS, withSass, withGraphql], nextConfig);
```

If I visit `http://host.url/other` directly, the `getInitialProps` method executes as expected. If I navigate to the page via a nextjs method, e.g. `Router.push` or a `<Link>` HOC, then the env variables returns undefined and I fall back to default values...

I'm obviously missing something here..please help!

All I want to do is have env variable `API_URL` available on my `other.tsx` page regardless of how I get there...

Comment: `getInitialProps` runs server side only on first render, that is how it works

Comment: I expected as much, but what alternative do I have? This is a show stopper for me at the moment. 

I've thought of saving a state somewhere on initial load, but it's becoming rather messy now

Comment: For the moment, I'm doing a check in the `_app.tsx` to `render()` see whether API_URL has already been set. If so, don't change it to the default...it works, but it's ugly...

Comment: you could use a custom `_document` to inject config to every page or wait for https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9524

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko I think that github issue will solve my problems. Will wait for that and use my current implementation as a hack in the meantime